# Как написать счетчик ОСТАЛОСЬ попыток 3

Tags: javascript

Вот мой скрипт. Не могу понять почему после ввода продолжает проверять цикл?
Задача следущая: При посещении страницы, необходимо попросить пользователя ввести свой пароль, после чего проверить содержит ли массив passwords пароль введенный пользователем. Пароль можно ввести не верно всего n раз.

написал вот такой скипт:

```
const passwords = ['qwerty', '111qwe', '123123', 'r4nd0mp4zzw0rd'];
let attemptsLeft = 3;
let i=1;
let input;

while (i <= attemptsLeft) {
  input = prompt('Введите пароль:');

  if (input === null) {
    break;
  }
  for (const pass of passwords) {
    if (pass === input) {
      alert('Добро пожаловать!');
      break;
    } 
    else if (i < attemptsLeft) {
      alert(`Неверный пароль, у вас осталось ${attemptsLeft - i} попыток`);
      break;
    } else {
      alert('У вас закончились попытки, аккаунт заблокирован!');
      break;
    }
  }
  i += 1;
}
```

Comment: Не нужно делать такие проверки через `js` они же бесполезные.

Comment: Потому что break при правильном пароле останавливает цикл `for`, а не 
цикл `while`.

Answer (score 1):

break останавливает ближайший к нему цикл. В вашем случае это for, так что while продолжает работать. По этому можно либо использовать метки, либо вынести часть с условным выражением из цикла.

про метки https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

про Array.prototype.some() https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```js
const passwords = ['qwerty', '111qwe', '123123', 'r4nd0mp4zzw0rd'];
let attemptsLeft = 3,
    i = 1,
    input;

while (i <= attemptsLeft) {
  input = prompt('Введите пароль:');

  if (input === null) {
    break;
  }
  
  if(passwords.some(password => password === input)){
      alert('Добро пожаловать!');
      break;
  } else if (i < attemptsLeft) {
      alert(`Неверный пароль, у вас осталось ${attemptsLeft - i} попыток`);
  } else {
      alert('У вас закончились попытки, аккаунт заблокирован!');
  }
  
  i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const passwords = ['qwerty', '111qwe', '123123', 'r4nd0mp4zzw0rd'];
let attemptsLeft = 3;
let i=1;
let input;
let isAllow = false;

main_loop:
while (i <= attemptsLeft) {
  input = prompt('Введите пароль:');
  if (input === null) {
    break;
  }
  for (const pass of passwords) {
    if (pass === input) {
      isAllow = true;
      break main_loop;
    } 
  }
  alert(`Неверный пароль, у вас осталось ${attemptsLeft - i} попыток`);
  i += 1;
}
if (isAllow) {
    alert('Добро пожаловать!');
}
else {
    alert('У вас закончились попытки, аккаунт заблокирован!');
}
```

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить комментарии к коду. Чем ваш код отличается от кода ТС? В чем была ошибка ТС?